# What is the percentage of Latino/Hispanic females with a Ph.D. degree?

Tags: phd

I am curious to know the percentage of Female Latino/Hispanic with Ph.D. degrees in the USA.
Does anyone know? What is the percentage of male/female out of the approx. 6% of Latino/Hispanic population with a Ph. D. (out of the of the 1.6% of all Americans with Ph. D. degrees)?

Thank you

Comment: Although the linked "duplicate" question doesn't directly address the breakdown by gender, the answers include links to data that I think does answer this.  I'd encourage you to see if that data answers your question, and if not, update this question to explain what's missing.

Comment: If I correctly read the Census data I linked in [this answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/111047/1010), it appears that among Hispanic people (by Census definition) with a doctoral degree, 53% are female.

Answer (score 0):

The NSF releases analysis on such data regularly: https://ncses.nsf.gov/pubs/nsf19304/

You can find a digest, as well as the source data, in case your particular question isn't answered by the digest.